# At what point are save transferable items from Witcher 1 available in Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2, the-witcher

I have downloaded an Ice Plains savedgame from online and edited it using a savedgame editor to equip Raven Armor, Ard'aenye and Moon Blade, as well as 999999999 Orens. I verified that I had these items equipped ingame. However, when I started my playthrough of Witcher 2, I had a blue Stripes Combat jacket and 2 random swords equipped, not the items I should get from the transfer.

When do I get these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed supposed to receive said items on the beggining of your playthrough. However, since the save game was tampered with, it's possible Witcher 2 couldn't recognize it correctly. Try finding a complete savegame with the rewards readily available without the need of editing (You can find those on Nexus Mods or similar websites).

Comment: Does the savegame have to have the items equipped, or does "in inventory" count as well?

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to have the items, not need to equip them. Also as Pyritie said, make sure you finish the tutorial (or skip it all together). That's the point you get your definitive starting gear.

Comment: with "have", you mean in your inventory, or does storage also count? The save I tried originally said "if you want to transfer your items over, you need to install a certain mod so you can access your storage in Act 5", but I wasn't sure how to do so. I used this one: http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/180/?

Answer (score 1):

Try completing the tutorial first before editing your save file. You will receive different starting gear (and lose your old stuff) when you finish the tutorial.